# DTO's naming convention

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions, dto

Probably it's a simple question, but I have no clear which is the best naming convention for dto's classes and packages, in terms of package name, uppercase DTO or Dto for classes, etc... Example:

**1. Package name:**

`xxx.dto.animal.Dog.class` or `xxx.animal.Dog.class`

**2. Uppercase dto Class Naming convention:**

`DogDTO` or `DogDto`

**3. Mixing both dto's conventions or neither.**

The problem is, if I can declare the 'dto' word as a package or if the word 'dto' has to be included on the class name or both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid DTO suffix in class names. Including DTO in package names are fine.

You just need to decide how to use it in package names. Usually, I prefer `my.feature1.dto`, `my.feature2.dto` for example.

DTO is a very simple class so it should not be hard to recognize class to be DTO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But about your comments, for example if we have a class converter with the dto's and the model(entity), How can you handle that? I mean, imagine that our model and the dto are quite similar... Hod do you manage the names? Dog(Dto) - Dog (model), the only different would be on the package..?

Comment: Can you give an example using some programming language? For example, if I use C#, I probably have something like: `my.feafure.dto.Dog` and `my.feature.model.Dog` My example can be bad but the main idea is that classes that have the same names are located in a different namespace. Probably models are inside different project also. IDEs are usually then good to see which package is used.

Comment: I understand the concept itself, but do you think in your class whatever is developed c#, java, kotlin etc has sense to have two Dog instances with same name  and different packages? I mean, **my.feafure.dto.Dog** and **my.feature.model.Dog**  in same class, at least it looks like strange, however if you have **my.feafure.dto.DogDto** and **my.feature.model.Dog**, the class is easier to understand because you see wihch object is the dto and which one is the model... Thta's the reason sometimes think is better include the dto in the name and other times i prefer not include it on it.

Comment: This is too ambiguous. As I said my example is bad. I have used DTO suffix many times but abandoned it later. There is nothing wrong to use the suffix so use it, if it is clear to you and your team.

I try to say that there is a probably better name for DTO class anyway. DTOs transfer data so usually I use suffix like xxxResponse, xxxRequest, xxxStatus etc. I know those classes just transfer data but now the intent is more clear than simple xxxDto suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is **consistency**!

- Don't mix conventions.
- If you work in a team on existing code, you have to be on the same page with them.

Otherwise, if you are refactoring a project or creating a new one, you can create a DTO folder and name your classes like the models, then use it as `DTO.Dog`.

Regarding the `DogDTO` VS `DogDto` question, I believe it depends on the language. In C# it would be `DogDto` based on [Microsoft Capitalization Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#capitalization-rules-for-identifiers)